# angular2 forms, selected item in <select> element

Tags: angular, typescript

Here's the `FormBuilder`:

```
let valuesArray = fb.array([
        fb.group({ name: 'one' }),
        fb.group({ name: 'two' }),
        fb.group({ name: 'three' }),
        fb.group({ name: 'four' })
    ]);

this.form = fb.group({
    values: valuesArray,
    selectedValue: valuesArray[0]
})
```

The template:

```
<select formControlName="selectedValue">
   <option *ngFor="let controlGroup of form.controls.values.controls">
     {{ controlGroup.controls.name.value }}
   </option>
</select>
```

This throws error `control.registerOnChange is not a function` which is fixed by removing the `formControlName` from `<select>` element, but how else would you keep track of selected items in the list?

Comment: Iterating over `form.controls.values.controls` looks quite wired.

Comment: Answered from Kara in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11669

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want:

```
<div>{{selectedItem | json}}</div>
<select formControlName="mySelect" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [(ngValue)]="item">
```

```
this.form = fb.group({
    mySelect: []
})

items = [
    { name: 'one' },
    { name: 'two' },
    { name: 'three' },
    { name: 'four' }];

selectedItem; 
// or
selectedItem = items[0];
```

Comment: That's template driven form... i don't want to use template driven forms. Thanks though.

Comment: then subscribe to `this.form.valueChanges...` instead of `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: Yes of course, but don't want to use banana box with reactive forms. I would rather use one or the other through entire application.

Comment: You mean `[(ngValue)]`. I don't think there is a way around it. `<option>` is not a control for forms, only `<select>` is.